# trpc .fetch in nextjs app router, does fetch() get deduped?

Tags: next.js, react-query, app-router, tanstackreact-query, trpc

Will a .fetch() call on a initTRPC.context, server side, be deduped by the nextjs app router or not?

From [nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts):
"Passing data between a parent layout and its children is not possible. However, you can fetch the same data in a route more than once, and React will automatically dedupe the requests without affecting performance."

From [tan-stack docs](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/guides/advanced-ssr):
"Next.js already dedupes requests that utilize fetch(), but if you are using something else in your queryFn, or if you use a framework that does not dedupe these requests automatically, using a single queryClient as described above might make sense, despite the duplicated serialization."